# Boundary Integral of products of known functions

Tags: real-analysis

I've been trying to figure out to say something about the product of two functions that I know the integral to. More specifically, some function $K$ and some linear function $a\cdot x$. I know the following:

$\int_{\Gamma} K \; ds_x = 1$

Is it possible to say anything about:

$\int_{\Gamma} K\cdot x \; ds_x = $ ?

I tried alot of standard methods like partial integration, however $K$ is a very tedious function to work with in this case. 
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you know something more about $K$, you can't say much at all. If all you know is $K\ge0$, all you can say is $$\int Kx\le\max_{x{\rm\ in\ }\Gamma}|x|$$ and a similar lower bound.

Comment: @AD., sounds like a good idea. I'll edit.

Comment: Now I believe it +1 ;)